# Loop through DIV elements using VBA

Tags: javascript, html, css, vb.net, vba

I'm having an issue with looping through div elements, well I dont know how to do it. The code is pretty much working.

Essentially I have access to a website and would like to download content from it via a link. My code looks and finds the element X and proceeds to click that element.

The issue is, element X is repeated numerous times, so for example .getElementByClassName("AssetLinkText") is repeated a couple of times in the HTML code resulting in the fetch downloading the first "AssetLinkText".

I was thinking the soulution would be to search through the HTML i.e. for each loop and look for the tag with the inner text "Download full securities list". However, I am unsure as to how to do this.

```
Sub anotherAttempt()

'DECLARE VARIABLES
Dim browser As InternetExplorer
Dim document As HTMLDocument
Set browser = New InternetExplorer
Dim div

'MAKE VIS AND NAV
browser.Visible = True
browser.Navigate "https://etf.deutscheam.com/GBR/ENG/ETF/LU1221100792/-/DAX-UCITS-ETF-(DR)-Income"

'MULTITHREAD
Do While browser.Busy And Not browser.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
      DoEvents
Loop

'PERFORM ACTIONS
Set document = browser.document
Dim anchorElement As HTMLAnchorElement
Set anchorElement = document.getElementsByClassName("AssetLinkText")
'CHECK FOR HOLDINGS LINK
anchorElement.Click

End Sub
```

Comment: vba and vb.net are not the same, this function [doesn't seem to exists](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument(v=vs.110).aspx) in vb.net  I dont' see any javascript either.

Comment: `Set anchorElement = document.getElementsByClassName("...")` gives you a list of elements, which means `anchorElement.Click` can never work. You can't click a list of elements. Your question is not clear on what you want to achieve.

Comment: look at the return for getElementsByClassName, it will return a collection, then use this to loop the collection.  The help files and the internet on Microsoft Internet Controls are a great source of information.

Comment: I was unable to find AssetLinkText in the HTML of the URL given in your code. Has something changed?

Answer (score 0):

This work with me.

```
Dim divs As Object
Dim div As Object

// get all div element in DOM
Set divs = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("div")

// loop through all div elements
For Each div In divs
    // do things here
    // e.g. div.innerHTML = "hello"
Next div
```

Comment: Please add explanation of your solution. see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer