# Pull a single span id value behind an iFrame

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, iframe

I am trying to pull a single value from a work website that refreshes every 5 minutes. I am using HTTP Get Request to do this. However, I am having problems pulling the actual number I want. It is a span id and it is behind an iFrame element. FlowWidget is the iframe's id. Here is my code I have already. I am new to VBA, so this was a done from a lot of just researching but now I am stuck. I am getting the error code "object variable or with block variable not set" on the "Set Number" line. Thanks to anyone willing to help.

```
        H.SetAutoLogonPolicy 0
        H.SetTimeOuts 0, 0, 0, 0
        H.Open "GET", URL, False
        H.send
        H.WaitForResponse


        If H.Status <> 200 Then
        MsgBox H.Status & " - " & H.statusText
        Exit Sub
        End If

        Debug.Print H.responseText

        doc.Body.innerHTML = H.responseText

       Dim elemCollection As IHTMLElementCollection

       Set elemCollection = doc.frames("FlowWidget").document.all
       Set Number = elemCollection.Item("force_induct_count_value").innerText

       Dim inductAmount As String

       If Not Number Is Nothing Then inductAmount = Number.innerText

       Set doc = Nothing

      Range("A1").Value = inductAmount

      End Sub
```

The span id I need from the web is like this:

```
<span id="force_induct_count_value" class="boson-text-size-4">19201</span>
```

Comment: Don't name your variable Number. Name it EleNumber.

You're also going to want to loop through the elemCollection, and find the item with that inner text. I believe Item("") is an integer value, so that line is expecting a number since Elemcollection.Item should be like this: Elemcollection.Item(1) or Elemcollection.Item(2)

So you would want to do this with span instead of div: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47568283/12685075

Comment: Thanks for the response. I changed it to eleNumber. Also where in my code do I add the code for looping through the spans like in the link you sent me?

Answer (score 0):

This should do it. I made the assumption that the ID will always be "force_induct_count_value". And if thats the case this should work. But you can probably just take the "Split" function and plug it into your subroutine.

```
 Set objHTTP = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
Url = ""
objHTTP.Open "POST", Url, False
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
objHTTP.send ("NA")
yourAnswer = Split(objHTTP.responseText, "force_induct_count_value")
yourAnswer = Split(yourAnswer(1), ">")
yourAnswer = Split(yourAnswer(1), "<")
Debug.Print yourAnswer(0)
```

Or in your code like this

Try adding it to your code like this. After you get your H.repsonseText

```
Debug.Print H.responseText

yourAnswer = Split(H.responseText, "force_induct_count_value")
yourAnswer = Split(yourAnswer(1), ">")
yourAnswer = Split(yourAnswer(1), "<")
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. It's really appreciated. The hardest project I have ever worked on. So I tried this and on the second "your answer" line it is giving me error code 9, "subscript out of range". And it seems due to the site needing permissions to access it i had to put line objHTTP.SetAutoLogonPolicy 0. Also the ID should always be the same like you assumed.

Comment: Try adding it to your code like this. And remember to approve the answer once we get it right!
```
Debug.Print H.responseText

yourAnswer = Split(H.responseText, "force_induct_count_value")
yourAnswer = Split(yourAnswer(1), ">")
yourAnswer = Split(yourAnswer(1), "<")
```

Comment: Hi again. Thank you for your response. So I tried them and no luck. Still getting "subscript out of range aroound the same line. A new code I have is this. It runs however, it does not result in any number being pulled into A1. Any thoughts on this. Thank you!
    
doc.body.innerHTML = doc.getElementById("FlowWidget")
Set eleNumber = doc.getElementById("force_induct_count_value")

    Dim forceInduct As String
    
    If Not eleNumber Is Nothing Then forceInduct = eleNumber.innerText

Set doc = Nothing

Range("A1").Value = forceInduct

Comment: In your original code, are you getting the entire html response when you debug.print(H.responseText)? And can you add the value from your debug.print(H.responseText) to your question so we can see it?

Comment: Yes, later when I am off I will update with the response text that is posted in the immediate window. The response does show up in the immediate window but I am not seeing the “span id” with the “force_induct_count_value” like I need. Maybe that’s where the issue is coming from? Should it show that particular line there? I see a lot of div > lines where nothing is showing underneath them. Whereas if you inspect the url on a browser there’s a bunch of elements under these div > lines.

Comment: Here is the response text that is received in the Immediate window upon running the code. 
                                                                     <iframe src="/station/block/flow-status-block/view?stationCode=station&cycleId=AllCycles" width="100%" height="100%" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" id="FlowWidget" data-blockname="FlowWidget"></iframe>
</div>
</div>
                        </div>
</div>
</div>
        </div>

Comment: I mean...if the response you are getting does not contain 
```<span id="force_induct_count_value" class="boson-text-size-4">19201</span>```
That is a problem. That information needs to be in the response if you are trying to capture the value.

Comment: There is a lot more in the response text but due to character limit on here I could not fit it all. So do you know why the line I need wouldn’t be in it? I do see the iframe line there I believe it is hidden behind.

Comment: Without seeing the full response and not knowing the web page, I have to guess a little. That ```<span>``` element could be being generated/updated by a client side script (JavaScript is adding it after the page is loaded). Regardless I do not think your issue is with VBA anymore. You have the VBA code needed to get the value. The next step is for us to understand why the element is not showing up in your http response.

Comment: I was doing some reading, I think you need to do your http request to the source of the Iframe element. Can you find the source of the iframe element?

Comment: Interesting. So I won’t have access to my work computer for the next couple of days to try it. But how would I find the source of the iframe element to do the http request through it?